# gitpython: How to show diffs between blobs in a human readable format, as in gitk?

Tags: gitpython

I must be missing something really basic.  Given this script:

```
import git
repo = git.Repo(r'C:/leo.repo/leo-editor') 
diff_index = repo.head.commit.diff('HEAD~1')
for d in diff_index:
    print('%s %9s %9s %s' % (
        d.change_type, id(d.a_blob), id(d.b_blob), d.a_path))
```

I get something like this:

```
M 173600704 173600080 leo/core/commit_timestamp.json
M 173600368 173599408 leo/core/leoTest.py
M 173600272 173598928 leo/test/unitTest.leo
```

So far, so good. This is compatible with what gitk shows, that is, modifications to the three files shown.

But now, having access to the a_blob and b_blob objects for each file, how do I get a human-readable diff of the differences between those two blobs? In other words, I want to recreate what gitk shows.

I don't see anything in the docs related to this.

Edward

Answer (score 1):

My question is a variant of [this stack-overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717790/gitpython-get-tree-and-blob-object-by-sha).

given a blob, blob.data_stream.read() returns its raw contents, that is a `<str>` object on Python 2, and a `<bytes>` object on Python 3.

Rather than reading the feeble [api docs for Objects.Blob](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#module-git.objects.blob), one would be better off reading the [source code](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/master/git/objects/blob.py). Indeed, Objects.Blob is a subclass of base.IndexObject, which in turn inherits the data_stream property from base.Object (not to be confused with object).

Comment: So how did you get the human readable diff between the two blobs?

Comment: @LondonAppDev As they have mentioned, once you have the blob object, you can read its raw contents by `blob.data_stream.read()`. And thanks to them, this is exactly what I was looking for, and it works really well too (I was trying to get the content of last commit, and compare it with the modified files in a GUI containing two panes). If there are any better ways to do this, please let me know :)