# List the content of a directory for a specific git commit using GitPython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

Using GitPython, I'm trying to list the content of a directory at a given commit (i.e. a "snapshot" of the directory at the time).

In the terminal, what I'd do is:

```
git ls-tree --name-only 4b645551aa82ec55d1794d0bae039dd28e6c5704
```

How can I do the same in GitPyhon?

Based on the answers I've found to a similar question ([GitPython get tree and blob object by sha](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10717790/222529)) I've tried recursively traversing `base_commit.tree` and its `.trees`, but I don't seem to get anywhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, traversing the trees/subtrees is the right approach. However, the built in `traverse` method can have issues with Submodules. Instead, we can do the traversal ourselves iteratively and find all the blob objects (which contain the files in our repo at a given commit). There's no need to use `execute`.

```py
def list_files_in_commit(commit):
    """
    Lists all the files in a repo at a given commit

    :param commit: A gitpython Commit object
    """
    file_list = []
    dir_list = []
    stack = [commit.tree]
    while len(stack) > 0:
        tree = stack.pop()
        # enumerate blobs (files) at this level
        for b in tree.blobs:
            file_list.append(b.path)
        for subtree in tree.trees:
            stack.append(subtree)
    # you can return dir_list if you want directories too
    return file_list
```

If you want the files affected by a given commit, this is available via `commit.stats.files`.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a more elegant way than actually calling `execute`.
This is the end result:

```
configFiles = repo.git.execute(
    ['git', 'ls-tree', '--name-only', commit.hexsha, path]).split()
```

where `commit` is a `git.Commit` object and `path` is the path I'm interested in.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the path to the directory, let's say it is `foo/bar/baz` and you have a GitPython `Commit` object, let's call it `commit` then you can access the `blobs` in the directory like so `commit.tree['foo']['bar']['baz'].blobs` and then get the individual blob (file) `name`s to come up with your list of files in that directory at the commit point in time.

```
import git

repo = git.Repo('path/to/my/repo')
commit = next(repo.iter_commits(max_count=1))
files_in_dir = [b.name for b in commit.tree['foo']['bar']['baz'].blobs]
```